# Flink 1.16 Application Starting Issue from Flink Cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I have updated the Flink version to 1.16.0, after that application itself not starting. Getting below error. We are running the flink in application mode since it was working fine in 1.15.

```
<flink.version>1.16.0</flink.version>
```

Pipeline file

```
./bin/flink run-application --target kubernetes-application -Dkubernetes.cluster-id=sqs-signal-ingress-cluster -Dkubernetes.namespace=dev-sqs -Dkubernetes.jobmanager.service-account=flink-service-account -Dkubernetes.container.image=acrccsdev.azurecr.io/ubs-changes-oct21-sqs-signal-ingress:2022-10-21.11_27294_sqs-signal-ingress_ubs-changes-oct21 -Dkubernetes.container.image.pull-secrets=dev-ccs-acr local:///opt/flink/usrlib/signal-ingress-job.jar
```

Getting the below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaSink]: Factory method 'kafkaSinkFsmStates' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader @10feca44 wants to load class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord. A different class with the same name was previously loaded by 'app'. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[signal-ingress-job.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[signal-ingress-job.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader @10feca44 wants to load class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord. A different class with the same name was previously loaded by 'app'. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

How can I run the Flink job after updating the 1.16 version

Comment: Is there anything to do with Kafka-clients version ?. Please suggest

Comment: I didn't think Spring integrated with Flink. If you're using Spring-kafka, then that could be the issue

Comment: Hey , we are not using spring kafka . Flink Application along with Spring framework. till 1.15 is working fine in the dev server , we are running as Application mode . but After creating a new cluster for 1.16 its giving the above error

Comment: Your Flink application and Spring framework most likely have conflicting dependencies. The Spring framework is not supported by Flink, so there's not much that Flink can do here.

Comment: You didn't share your dependencies, so we cannot see what you are using. You should share `mvn dependency:tree`